# in Ruby open IO object and pass each line to another object

Tags: ruby, zip

I need to download a large zipped file, unzip it and modify each string before I save them to array.

I prefer to read downloaded zipped file line(entry) at a time, and manipulate each line(entry) as they load, rather then load the whole file in the memory.

I experimented with many IO methods of opening a file this way, but I struggle to pass a line(entry) to Zip::InputStream object. This is what I have:

```
require 'tempfile'
require 'zip'
require 'open-uri'

f = open(FILE_URL) #FILE_URL contains download path to .zip file

  Zip::InputStream.open(f) do |io|  #io is a String
    while (io.get_next_entry)
     io.each do |line|  
      # manipulate the line and push it to an array
     end
    end
 end
```

if I use `open(FILE_URL).each do |zip_entry|`, I cannot figure out how to pass `zip_entry` to `Zip::InputStream`. Simply `Zip::InputStream.open(zip_entry)` does not work...

is this scenario possible, or do I have to have content of zipped file downloaded in to Tempfile completely? Any pointers so solve will be helpful

Comment: instead of `io.each` what is returned through `io.read` ?

Comment: Why are you passing through a line of text to `Zip::InputStream`? It wants a filehandle from `open` or a filename.

Comment: @tadman I did not want to download  .zip file on the disk. `open(FILE_URL)` returns a Tempfile object. I just could not fins a way to open file that needs to be downloaded first, so I thought I pass it a File object. is there another way to do that? I am lost. The code works, but know sure it is the right way to go

Comment: @gmaliar `io.read` returns a whole flle uncompressed as a string.

Comment: @gmaliar I was actually puzzled to see that this block uncompresses the file without `read` method... I also found some errors in unzipped file - some of the entries have last number replaced by 0.!

Comment: Using the temporary file is the way to do this since you have no apparent need to permanently save it. What's the problem? If it works, great, move on to the next problem. I think you'll be able to address any problems of elegance here when you've got a better grip on Ruby in general.

Comment: @tadman I have a real hard time to formulate a question. How can I pass a download stream/file to Zip module in more efficient way?  But as you stated, I can worry about that later :) Thank you for your input!

Comment: There's nothing inefficient with this approach. Inelegant, maybe, but that can be fixed later.